# Podman how remove all exited containers if there are many

Tags: linux-containers, podman, redhat-containers

On a server running containers with Podman I just realised, there are many containers with "Exited" status and wanted to remove all of them in one go.

How can I do it with Podman?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching for some time I found a quick and easy one liner to get my exited containers cleaned.

One option is:

```
podman rm -f $(podman ps -a -f "status=exited" -q)
```

The second option is:

```
podman ps -f status=exited --format "{{.ID}}" | xargs podman rm -f
```

A big thanks to [dannotdaniel](https://coderwall.com/p/zguz_w/docker-remove-all-exited-containers) for the second option. This saved me at least an hour. :)

Answer (score 17):

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-container-prune.1.html) there is a specific command for just that purpose:

> Remove all stopped containers from local storage:

```
podman container prune
```